# How to understand that the app is being closed with the TaskManager?

Tags: android

Is there a way to catch this kind of event?

UPD:

I want to collect information about how often do person closes my app this way. It's going to be a joke: when user closes the app with task killer very often - he gets special behaviour.

That's the minimum requirements.

Comment: Can we have a bit more information? Why do you want to do this? There might be another answer which can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Activity method `isFinishing()` to check if your application is being finished from calling `finish()` or if it is being shut down otherwise.
I'm not sure if you can tell the difference between task killer kills and other types of kills (such as when the system runs low on memory).

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think onDestroy() is what you are looking for.

This is called before an activity is destroyed.

Comment: `onDestroy` isn't called when you force close an app, from the Settings menu for example

Comment: I will have to test that this evening, did not realize that.